# Is it ok to repeatedly intentionally fail a DB insert on duplicate row?

Tags: android, sql

Is it okay to hit many "Duplicate row on insert" when inserting into the sql db or is there a better way?

I am downloading "comments" from my server and displaying them in a listview on my android phone..

Here is how I do it:

1 - Whenever I display the listview, I fetch that last 15 comments via xml from the server..

2 - I insert the comments into a local sql database on the phone

3 - I update the listview by using an adapter that loads the data from the local sql database.

Every 30 seconds I am repeating steps 1, 2 and 3.. I also repeat steps 1, 2, and 3 when the activity hits onResume...

Unless another android client has uploaded a new comment, all comments fetched from server are duplicates and inserting them into the db returns an SQLConstraintException because I don't allow duplicates of the same comment.

Is this okay? I am throwing this exception for 10-15 rows every 30 seconds.. Is there a better way that wont hurt performance? I don't see the point of checking if the row exists before insert, since that will surely be slower.. I could potentially pass a variable to the server when I query it, telling it what my newest comment is..

I'm sure *many many* people have reached this crossroads. Where should we go from here?

Thanks for the discusson..

Comment: have you considered about checking the unique keys of the comments you are fetching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your server's db has a sequential, incremental key then yes, I would just query with an additional condition "...AND SeqIdField > [my last id]". If no records are returned then you just reset your timer and wait to query again.

Even if there's no sequential id but you can get records inserted after a particular date/time then just make sure that date/time is included in your results and pass the latest one back in as a parameter. If you don't want / need to store that date/time on your local device then just save the latest somewhere so you know where to pick back up when your app runs again.

Comment: At the moment the client is requesting the last 15 comments from the server - regardless of if the client has already received them. It sounds like you are suggesting that I request the last 15 comments that the client doesn't already have. I think I'll go ahead and make this change since if nothing else, it will save network bandwidth.. Why push the same 15 comments to the client over and over. Cheers~

Comment: OK, in that case you probably need 2 queries. First, fetch everything you don't already have as I suggested. If that results in 15 or more rows then you won't need to execute the second query. If you get fewer than 15 rows, execute another query for everything older than the last record you got in the first query and prepend the "TOP n" keyword where n=how many more rows you need. This will result in the absolute fewest number of records being sent over the wire.